# Unable to see device in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, virtual-machine, device

So just recently I updated xcode from 8.3.3 to 9, and swift 3 to swift 4. I did this so that I could use the newest version of iOS 11. The problem is, that now I am unable to see my device as an option to run my app on. Not sure if I accidentally turned on some setting or the conversion messed something up.

I am running High Sierra on a VM, with Windows as the host. I had to add High Sierra as a new OS to install xcode 9. This is my 3rd Mac OS on the VM with the same exact settings as the two previous versions, and the device works perfectly on the other versions (El Capitan, and Sierra). So I don't see the VM as the problem (although I am not ruling it out).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are talking about `Wireless Developing` you have to connect your device once via USB cable and enable `Connect via network`

Comment: I do connect the device via USB cable, it sees the device fine on the other versions of Mac OS, just not High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your iOS device and try connecting it to Xcode again. In some occurences, this is the only method that works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your VM software fully supports High Sierra as a guest OS. High Sierra might not contain the same drivers as previous versions for whatever hardware your VM host is emulating. Can you connect other USB devices to the VM?

Also, you don't need High Sierra to run Xcode 9. Xcode 9 requires a Mac running macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later.

Comment: It connects my mouse just fine. When I connect my device via USB cable, I hear a connect and a disconnect sounds one right after the other. Just noticed that, trying to investigate.

Comment: I am almost certain that this is a VM problem. And version 10.12.6 is the earliest occurrence of this issue. So even if I updated my disk, the problem would persist. Still not sure how to fix it tho.

Comment: @SlavictheSlavic If you think so, perhaps you should update your question with details about your VM setup and maybe also try looking for help somewhere else ([Super User](https://superuser.com) comes to mind, or maybe one of the hackintosh forums), since this is not exactly a programming issue.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll go ahead and check out a few other forums.